# How do I make komodo edit open stuff with mac line breaks?

Tags: windows-7, mac, linebreaks, komodo-edit

I'm on my Windows 7 PC using Komodo Edit text editor (version 6.1).

I have a file from my Mac which I need to use, but it either doesn't open or opens as a blank doc.

The file isn't broken or anything, as I can open it in Word.

Would this problem be caused by the Mac-style line breaks in the file? If so, is there a way to make Komodo Edit for Windows understand the Mac line breaks? And, if not, what is causing the issue?

Comment: Why are you so sure it's a linebreak issue? What kind of file are you trying to open?

Comment: the output from Mauve genome aliger (the alignment itself and exported SNPs), it opens fine on the mac as a plain text file. also opens fine in other programs which open text files.